# What is the operator `|=`? How can I implement this in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, operators

What is the C++ code below doing? More specifically, what is the operator `|=`?

```
long liFaultFlags = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < FAULTCOUNT; i++)
{
    if (faults[i] == true)
    {
        liFaultFlags |= (1 << i);
    }
}

return liFaultFlags;
```

How would this be implemented in C#?

Comment: The answers below are correct with the glaring omission of needing to note that in C++, operators can be overloaded to mean different things, although in your case it looks as if you're interacting with two basic numeric types, which means that the behavior should be as-expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is the [bitwise OR operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) and is equivalent to

```
liFaultFlags = liFaultFlags | (1<<i);
```

You would write that line in exactly the same way in C#.

Comment: For pedantry's sake, I would call it 'bitwise OR' rather than 'binary OR'.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "binary bitwise OR", where binary refers to the type of operator rather than the data it's dealing with?

Comment: "binary" is technically wrong. There can be no *unary* OR (bitwise or other). Pedantic, like ildjarn says :)

Comment: I get this warning in VS2008 when running `liFaultFlags |= (1<<i);` in C#: `Warning: Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand; consider casting to a smaller unsigned type first.` Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, I definitely meant to type "bitwise"... corrected.

Comment: @Ryan R: Look at your data types and read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdc6717a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Jon Old message I know, but I can't resist!  "There can be no _unary_ OR..." Oh, I thought so too at some point in my life: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL#Operators

Answer (score 8):

The [operator `|=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) does bitwise OR and assignment rolled into one (much like += does integer addition and assignment together).

It's exactly the same in C#.