# What is |= assignment operator?

Tags: c#, .net, binary, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this operator “|=”? How can I implement this in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492747/what-is-this-operator-how-can-i-implement-this-in-c)

Can you explain what is the opearator:"|=" ?

For example here how should I read it:

```
_isChanged |= ( _pk_country != value );
```

Answer (score 3):

`if _isChanged == true` it will stay true

`if _isChanged == false` it will become the result of `_pk_country != value`

Comment: So it means it is equivalent to _isChanged || ( _pk_country != value );

Comment: right: `_isChanged = _isChanged || ( _pk_country != value );`

Answer (score 1):

a |= b is simply a shorthand notation for a = a | b. Same goes for the same notation for other operators. In short, you could say something like:

a [operator]= b is equivalent to a = a [operator] b

Answer (score 1):

Betwise OR

1 | 0  = 1

0 | 1  = 1

0 | 0  = 0

1 | 1  = 1

Regards.

Comment: What was the reason for downvoting? People on this site make very fast desicions sometimes... It's not just like Like/Dislike of Facebook, even if Facebook doesn't have Dislike option...